# ng-hide is not working in autocomplete md-not-found

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular, I have an auto complete which has md-not-found. I need to hide if my mode is 3. not found alwasy displys no matter what the value in mode. Is there a way to hide not found? following is my code.

```
<md-autocomplete id="autoCompleteSearchBox"
                     class="search-box search-auto-complete" flex tabindex="0"
                     ng-disabled="!!vm.isDisabled"
                     md-no-cache="!!vm.noCache"
                     md-min-length="1"
                     md-delay="50"
                     md-selected-item="vm.selectedItem"
                     md-search-text="vm.text"
                     md-items="item in vm.query(vm.text)"
                     md-item-text="item.display"
                     md-selected-item-change="vm.selectItem()"
                     md-search-text-change="vm.reset()"
                     md-select-on-match="true"
                     md-input-id="txt_search"
                     placeholder="{{vm.hint()}}"
                     on-enter
                     md-autofocus>

        <md-item-template ng-if="vm.masterMode !==3">
            <div layout="row" layout-align="space-between center" style="max-height: 32px">
                <span md-highlight-text="vm.search.text" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.display}}</span>
                <span>({{item.count}})</span>
            </div>
        </md-item-template>
            <md-not-found  ng-hide="vm.masterMode===3">
                    Search for "{{vm.text}}".
            </md-not-found>
    </md-autocomplete>
```

Answer (score 1):

Now it is working, check my code, It will be hidden after three seconds:

```js
angular.module("app", []).controller("MyController", function($scope) {
  $scope.vm = {};
  $scope.vm.masterMode = 0;
  setTimeout(function(){ 
        $scope.$apply(function(){
            $scope.vm.masterMode = 3;
        });
    }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyController"><md-autocomplete id="autoCompleteSearchBox"
                     class="search-box search-auto-complete" flex tabindex="0"
                     ng-disabled="!!vm.isDisabled"
                     md-no-cache="!!vm.noCache"
                     md-min-length="1"
                     md-delay="50"
                     md-selected-item="vm.selectedItem"
                     md-search-text="vm.text"
                     md-items="item in vm.query(vm.text)"
                     md-item-text="item.display"
                     md-selected-item-change="vm.selectItem()"
                     md-search-text-change="vm.reset()"
                     md-select-on-match="true"
                     md-input-id="txt_search"
                     placeholder="{{vm.hint()}}"
                     on-enter
                     md-autofocus>

        <md-item-template ng-if="vm.masterMode !==3">
            <div layout="row" layout-align="space-between center" style="max-height: 32px">
                <span md-highlight-text="vm.search.text" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.display}}</span>
                <span>({{item.count}})</span>
            </div>
        </md-item-template>
            <md-not-found  ng-hide="vm.masterMode == 3">
                    Search for "{{vm.text}}".
            </md-not-found>
    </md-autocomplete></div>
```

Comment: But in my case it is not working may be some bug in Angular 1.4 :(

Comment: You got to deep down in your code and compare with mine, you will find the thing causes bugs in yours, If you can indicate the differences I may have some opinions to tell ya